# Angular js Select reset

Tags: angularjs

I have a angular select drop down with ng-options and ng-model and two input text boxes.when i select last option in drop down text boxes are enabled which are disabled by default.If i am selecting last value in drop down text boxes are enabling and on reload of page i made condition to select a option with empty value.And when i select last option again still text boxes are in disabled mode

```
 Rangeslicer += "<div id='Rangeslicer"+id+"'>"
            Rangeslicer += " <select class='selectpicker' id='rangepicker" + id + "' data-ng-change='RangeSelection(" + '"' + id + '"' + ")'   ng-options='dayNames as dayNames.dayName for dayNames in RangeSelector' style='border-radius:5px;height:25px;outline:0px;text-align:center'>"
            //   Rangeslicer += " <select id='rangepicker" + id + "'   ng-options='dayNames.id as dayNames.dayName for dayNames in RangeSelector' style='border-radius:20px;height:25px;outline:0px;text-align:center' ng-model='rangepicker" + id + "'>"
            Rangeslicer += " <option value=''>Select Date Range</option>"
            Rangeslicer += "</select>   <br/>"
            Rangeslicer += " <div id='custominput' style='margin-top:4%'><input type='text' class='daterangecustom" + id + "  datecustom' id='customstart" + id + "'  disabled ng-model='customstart' style='height:25px;border-radius:5px;width:35%;margin-right:10%;margin-left:3%;text-align:center;outline:0px'/><input type='text'   class='daterangecustom" + id + "   datecustom' id='customend" + id + "'  disabled ng-model='customend' ng-mouseleave='compareDates(" + '"' + id + '"' + ")' style='border-radius:5px;width:35%;height:25px;text-align:center;outline:0px'/></br><p id='errormessage" + id + "' style='display:none;margin-bottom:0px'>Please ensure that the End Date is greater than or equal to the Start Date.</p></div></div>"
            //$compile($('#Rangeslicer').empty())($scope);
            //    $compile($("#divChk" + id).empty())($scope);

            $compile($("#main" + id).append(Rangeslicer))($scope);


 $('select.selectpicker option:first').prop('selected', true);
```

Actually when option is changed to last value textboxes should enable

Comment: It would probably be better if this was it's own directive instead of relying on the building and compiling manually.  But anyhow, could you try doing `ng-disabled="isLastItemSelected()"` instead of however you're adding/removing the `disable` flag now?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-disabled="lastSelected()"` on your inputs, where `lastSelected` is a function that checks if the ng-model value on your select is the empty item.